# How to set Digital Signature in a box provided in PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature, digital

In my PDF I am having one box I want to place digital signature in that box..How can I do it using iTextSharp.
[image]

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper stamper = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, fout, '\0');

iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont bf = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/files/Arial.ttf"), iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 11);
appearance.Layer2Font = font;
//appearance.Image = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfImage();
appearance.Reason = "Test";
appearance.Location = "Pune";

appearance.SetVisibleSignature("SignHere");
IExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-256");
MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, es, new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { pk12.GetCertificate(alias).Certificate }, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
stamper.Close();
```

Comment: How can that box be recognized? Is it always at the same position? If not, how is it drawn (vector graphics? Bitmap? Somehow else?) Is the text in the box always the same?

Comment: PDF is generated using SSRS RDL report. Text will be the same always but position may change

Comment: How is it drawn (vector graphics? Bitmap? Somehow else?) You may want to share a representative example file.

Comment: Another approach is: Can you influence the PDF which is created? I once implemented a mechanism where a customer would embedd a white text on a white page ("@signature here") and afterwards you could scan the PDF for this specific text and add a signature field at that location...